# How to hide menu element with only CSS

Tags: html, css, hide, display

I have these menu elements I am trying to hide but I cannot seem to only select the middle option called 'Contact'. I cannot edit the html directly so am using CSS to override the style.

Essentially I just want to hide the item called 'Contact' from appearing. How do I select it using CSS? I have put what I thought might work in the  section, but it's not really working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. (Here it is as well: https://jsfiddle.net/amhzv0Lw/4/)

Here's the menu code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .nav a[title:contact] {
        display: none;
    } 
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
<li><a href="/www.example.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/www.example.com/storepage.aspx" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.example.com/login" title="Login">Login</a></li>



    </ul>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to replace `:` with `=`, because that's how css selectors work (reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp))

Your code should look like this

```
<style>
    .nav a[title=Contact] {
        display: none;
    } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use CSS `nth-child` selectors this way:

```
.nav li:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Or may provide a CSS class to that "Contact" list-item, and hide it with CSS:

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><a href="://www.example.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="://www.example.com/storepage.aspx" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/login" title="Login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.nav li:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>With CSS nth-child selector</h3>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><a href="/www.example.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/www.example.com/storepage.aspx" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/login" title="Login">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>With CSS classes</h3>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><a href="/www.example.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="/www.example.com/storepage.aspx" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/login" title="Login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**: Note that the below CSS will hide only the hyperlink, not the list-item:

```
.nav a[title=Contact] {
  display: none;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is the best I love the idea of nth-child(2). Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, it works : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amhzv0Lw/7/)

```
.nav a[title=Contact] {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly, this is why I love the stack community :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.nav>li:nth-child(2){
   display:none;
}
```

please check out the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/amhzv0Lw/9/

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of doing this-

> **Method 1-**  Targetting the li through nth-child selector property.

```
.nav li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

> **Method 2-** You can also target the li with title attribute.

```
.nav a[title=Contact] {
        display: none;
    }
```